# dd immidiately completes but actually needs sync

Tags: linux, usb, dd

I use dd to copy an iso to a USB drive. I have a SSD so it reads it very fast however I have a USB 2.0 drive, which is at most 480 Mbps but it says it copied with 404 MB/s, which is impossible. I need to do `sync` after my `dd`. I used sync flag in dd, but it did not help, what should I do?

```
$dd if=ubuntu-13.10-server-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=1M conv=sync,noerror
672+0 records in
672+0 records out
704643072 bytes (705 MB) copied, 1,74625 s, 404 MB/s
```

And it is my kernel:

```
$ uname -a
Linux C3PO 3.11.0-18-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 18 21:11:14 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`conv=sync` does not activate synchronous input or output:

> pad every input block with NULs to ibs-size; when used with block or unblock, pad with spaces rather than NULs

Instead, you might want to try `conv=fdatasync`:

> physically write output file data before finishing

More intuitive is of course `oflag=sync`:

> dsync – use synchronized I/O for data
>
> sync – likewise, but also for metadata

Source: `man 1 dd`